# Question regarding changing coordinates systems using Jacobian Matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, jacobian

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78510/derive-vector-gradient-in-spherical-coordinates-from-first-principles

Here  ,the  Jacobian  Matrix  ,takes  3 functions  that  are  made  of **r, θ, Φ**  and  helps  it  to  transform  to  **x ,y ,z**  (ie) it  basically  acts like  a transformation  matrix  ,my  question  is

1)Is  my  assumption  of  changing  from  Spherical  to  Cartesian coordinates  correct  ,Is  that  the  function  of  **Jacobian Matrix**
here?

2)If  it  is ,then  shouldn't the  LHS  to  the  equal  sign  have  x,y,z terms , kind of  like  basis  vectors ,because  it  is  taking in  r,θ,Φ and transforming  to  x,y,z.

[image: Jacobian used to convert from Spherical to Cartesian Coordinate System]

Answer (score 1):

Take the function $f:U:=\mathbb R^+\times(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)\to \mathbb R^3$ such that
$$f(r,\theta,\phi)=(r\sin\theta\cos\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi,r\cos\theta)=(x(r,\theta,\phi),y(r,\theta,\phi),z(r,\theta,\phi)).$$
This map induces a linear function on tangent spaces that acts on tangent vectors:
$$f_{*p}:T_pU\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb R^3.$$
If you now take the basis of the tangent space $T_pU$, which is $\{\partial_{r},\partial_{\theta},\partial_{\phi}\}$, we can find their images in terms of $x,y,z$ coordinates through the computation of $f_{*p}(\partial_r),f_{*p}(\partial_{\theta}),f_{*p}(\partial_{\phi})$.
For example,
$$f_{*p}(\partial _r)=\dfrac{\partial x(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial r}\vert_p\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\vert_{f(p)}+\dfrac{\partial y(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial r}\vert_p\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\vert_{f(p)}+\dfrac{\partial z(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial r}\vert_p\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\vert_{f(p)}$$
and do the same for the other two coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$.
In general, the expression for $f_{*}(\partial_r)$ is given by
$$f_*(\partial_r)=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}\circ f^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}
+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}\circ f^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial r}\circ f^{-1}\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
because in this way we'll have the push foward of tangent vectors expressed in $x,y,z$ coordinates ($f$ has to be a diffeomorphism).
The Jacobian of $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ evaluated at a point $p\in U$ acts on tangent vectors $T_pU\ni v=a\partial_r+b\partial_{\theta}+c\partial_{\phi}$ as the matrix of representation of the linear operator $f_{*p}$.